# Jar/Class problems with Jetty WebSockets

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a problem with WebSockets. Carried out by a Java development environment IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6 using Jetty 9.1.0 and Maven.
I created two classes (code below).
Class WsHandler:

```
public class WsHandler extends WebSocketHandler {
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Set<EventWebSocket>> eventsSubscribers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest request, String protocol) {
    return new EventWebSocket();
}

private void fireEvent(String eventName) {
    Set<EventWebSocket> subscribers = eventsSubscribers.get(eventName);
    System.out.println("Event " + eventName + " was occurred. Subscribers " + subscribers);
    if (subscribers != null) {
        for (EventWebSocket webSocket : subscribers) {
            webSocket.onEvent(eventName);
        }
    }
}

public final class EventWebSocket implements WebSocket.OnTextMessage {

    private Connection connection;
    private List<String> subscribedEvents = new LinkedList();

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
        System.out.println("Open connection " + connection);
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data) {
        System.out.println("Process msg: " + data);
        if (data.isEmpty()) return;
        if (data.startsWith("Sub")) { // subscribe
            if (data.length() < 5) return;
            String eventName = data.split(":")[1]; // subscribing message format "Sub:EventName"
            Set<EventWebSocket> subscribers = eventsSubscribers.get(eventName);
            // double-check idiom for lazy initialization
            if (subscribers == null) {
                synchronized (EventHandler.class) {
                    if (eventsSubscribers.get(eventName) == null) {
                        subscribers = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
                        eventsSubscribers.putIfAbsent(eventName, subscribers);
                    }
                }
            }
            subscribers.add(this);
            subscribedEvents.add(eventName);
        } else if (data.startsWith("Fire")) { // fire event
            if (data.length() < 6) return;
            String eventName = data.split(":")[1]; // Fire event message format "Fire:EventName"
            fireEvent(eventName);
        } else {
            try {
                connection.sendMessage("Unknown command: " + data);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Ooops: " + ex + ". Close connection " + connection);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onEvent(String eventName) {
        try {
            connection.sendMessage("Event " + eventName + " was occurred");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Ooops: " + ex + ". Close connection " + connection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int closeCode, String message) {
        System.out.println("Close connection " + connection);
        // remove from subscribers
        for (String eventName : subscribedEvents) {
            eventsSubscribers.get(eventName).remove(this);
        }
    }
}}
```

Class SimpleEchoClien:

```
public class SimpleEchoClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WsHandler handler = new WsHandler();
    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}}
```

Run and get the error:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\Documents\java\Shooter\target\classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\lib\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.19\freemarker-2.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\9.1.0.M0\jetty-server-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\9.1.0.M0\jetty-http-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.1.0.M0\jetty-util-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.1.0.M0\jetty-io-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\9.1.0.M0\jetty-webapp-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\9.1.0.M0\jetty-xml-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\9.1.0.M0\jetty-servlet-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\9.1.0.M0\jetty-security-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-rewrite\9.1.0.M0\jetty-rewrite-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-client\9.1.0.M0\jetty-client-9.1.0.M0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.8.4\mockito-all-1.8.4.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\2.4.0\selenium-java-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-android-driver\2.4.0\selenium-android-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.4.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.4.0\selenium-api-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\r09\guava-r09.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.2\httpclient-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.4.0\selenium-chrome-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-htmlunit-driver\2.4.0\selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.8\htmlunit-2.8.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.0.1\httpmime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j\0.6\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.8\htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.9.1\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.14\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.5\cssparser-0.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.0.1\commons-io-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.4.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.4.0\selenium-ie-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.2.3\jna-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-iphone-driver\2.4.0\selenium-iphone-driver-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\2.4.0\selenium-support-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-websocket\7.4.4.v20110707\jetty-websocket-7.4.4.v20110707.jar;C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain servlets.SimpleEchoClient
2013-12-01 00:52:53.727:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.0.M0
2013-12-01 00:52:53.747:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED servlets.WsHandler@267a1e1c: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketHandler.doStart(WebSocketHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at servlets.SimpleEchoClient.main(SimpleEchoClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketHandler.doStart(WebSocketHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at servlets.SimpleEchoClient.main(SimpleEchoClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
2013-12-01 00:52:53.748:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@1b4ed400: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketHandler.doStart(WebSocketHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at servlets.SimpleEchoClient.main(SimpleEchoClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

With what the problem could be related? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to reduce the code to something shorter that still reproduces the issue you have? Do you really think someone will be willing to trawl through all this code?

Comment: @JanDvorak his code, and error message, are trivial and obvious to those that work with Jetty.  The question itself is information-rich, contrary to many questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, your command line, decomposed to make it readable:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" 
  -Didea.launcher.port=7532 
  "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\bin" 
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
  -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\deploy.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\javaws.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\management-agent.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\plugin.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\Documents\java\Shooter\target\classes
    C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\lib\junit-4.10.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.19\freemarker-2.3.19.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\9.1.0.M0\jetty-server-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\9.1.0.M0\jetty-http-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.1.0.M0\jetty-util-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.1.0.M0\jetty-io-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\9.1.0.M0\jetty-webapp-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\9.1.0.M0\jetty-xml-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\9.1.0.M0\jetty-servlet-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\9.1.0.M0\jetty-security-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-rewrite\9.1.0.M0\jetty-rewrite-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-client\9.1.0.M0\jetty-client-9.1.0.M0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.8.4\mockito-all-1.8.4.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\2.4.0\selenium-java-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-android-driver\2.4.0\selenium-android-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.4.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.4.0\selenium-api-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\r09\guava-r09.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.2\httpclient-4.0.2.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.4.0\selenium-chrome-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-htmlunit-driver\2.4.0\selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.8\htmlunit-2.8.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.0.1\httpmime-4.0.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j\0.6\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.8\htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.9.1\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.14\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.5\cssparser-0.9.5.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.0.1\commons-io-2.0.1.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.4.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.4.0\selenium-ie-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.2.3\jna-3.2.3.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-iphone-driver\2.4.0\selenium-iphone-driver-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\2.4.0\selenium-support-2.4.0.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-websocket\7.4.4.v20110707\jetty-websocket-7.4.4.v20110707.jar
    C:\Users\Alexandr.Alexandr-PC\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar
    C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar" 
  com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain servlets.SimpleEchoClient
```

And your first line of output from your program

```
2013-12-01 00:52:53.727:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.0.M0
```

You have multiple things to take care of.

1. You are running mixed versions of Jetty. Your jetty websockets is at `7.4.4.v20110707` while the rest of Jetty is at `9.1.0.M0`.
2. You should upgrade to the final (non-milestone, non-release candidate) version of Jetty 9.1 for the most mature websocket implementation.  That would be jetty `9.1.0.v20131115`
3. Your code example is for the early draft implementations of websocket, and shows you are looking at some extremely old code examples.  Would discourage you from using that long since deprecated API.
4. Your version of Java is old. 1.7 update 17 expired back in June (yes, Java versions expire.  Read the release notes. eg: [u40 expires on 12/10/2013](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u40-relnotes-2004172.html), and [u45 expires on 1/14/2014](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html))
5. Use either the **Modern Jetty WebSocket API**, or the **javax.websocket standard API**.

**Modern Jetty WebSocket API**

An example project has been setup at:

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/tree/master/native-jetty-websocket-example

The maven dependencies you'll need:

```xml
<!-- To write basic websockets against -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
</dependency>
<!-- To run websockets in embedded server -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
</dependency>
<!-- To run websockets client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
</dependency>
```

Look at the example code.

- [`EventServer.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServer.java) - this the jetty embedded server code, to initialize the handler tree + ServletContext.  It maps the `EventServlet` to the path spec of `"/events/*"`
- [`EventServlet.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServlet.java) - this simply registers the `EventSocket` with the Servlet (For background, the WebSocketServletFactory has a simple default implementation of [`WebSocketCreator`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/WebSocketCreator.html) that only supports 1 websocket.  The `.register(Class<?>)` call simply tells this default WebSocketCreator what WebSocket to create.  If you want a more complex WebSocketCreator, then you would call [`WebSocketServletFactory.setCreator(WebSocketCreator)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/WebSocketServletFactory.html#setCreator%28org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketCreator%29) with your own implementation)
- [`EventSocket.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventSocket.java) - the actual websocket that receives the incoming events
- [`EventClient.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventClient.java) - since your demo code was called client, but had server code in it, I didn't really know what you were planning, so i tossed in a Native Jetty WebSocket Client example as well.

**javax.websocket standard API on Jetty**

An example project has been setup at:

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/tree/master/javax.websocket-example

The maven dependencies you'll need:

```xml
<!-- To write basic javax.websocket against -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- To run javax.websocket in embedded server -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
</dependency>
<!-- To run javax.websocket client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax-websocket-client-impl</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
</dependency>
```

Look at the example code.

- [`EventServer.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/javax.websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServer.java) - this is slightly different than the Native API, as everything in the javax.websocket world is based on Annotations with discovery.  So this embedded server establishes a ServletContextHandler, then initializes the javax.websocket layer with a call to `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context)`, finally with a manual [`addEndpoint(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html#addEndpoint%28java.lang.Class%29) against the [`ServerContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html).
- [`EventSocket.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/javax.websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventSocket.java) - using the annotations for javax.websocket, this class is both annotated to be a Server endpoint and a Client endpoint, with the methods that should receive the various events also annotated to indicate their desired purpose.
- [`EventClient.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/javax.websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventClient.java) - this uses the javax.websocket [WebSocketContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/WebSocketContainer.html) (client container) to connect to the server and send a message.  (of particular note, is the extra work to cleanup the lifecycle of the WebSocketContainer.  a missing feature from the JSR-356 spec)

Good luck

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: is there a way to specify path spec if using "javax.websocket standard API "?

Comment: @eprst path spec to a specific websocket endpoint is supported by both the Jetty WebSocket API (supports: servlet path spec, uri template path spec, and regex path spec) and the javax.websocket API (only supports level 1 uri template path spec).